# mysql divison by zero error when using Like

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use PHP to update column data but I am receiving a division by zero error.

```
$find= "INSERT INTO closed_route( name, lat, latasal ) 
SELECT markers.name, markers.lat, user_locationtemp.lat AS some_name
FROM markers, user_locationtemp
WHERE markers.lat LIKE CONCAT( user_locationtemp.lat,  "%" )"; 
$result = mysql_query($find);
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quote around `%`

```
$find= "INSERT INTO closed_route( name, lat, latasal ) 
SELECT markers.name, markers.lat, user_locationtemp.lat AS some_name
FROM markers, user_locationtemp
WHERE markers.lat LIKE CONCAT( user_locationtemp.lat,  '%' )"; 
$result = mysql_query($find);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your quotes. When you write `"%"`, you're ending the string that began with `"INSERT`. So you're running the PHP `%` operator on the two strings, which is modulo. And since `"' )"` isn't a number, it's treated as zero, so you get division by zero.

Change to single quotes inside the string:

```
$find= "INSERT INTO closed_route( name, lat, latasal ) 
SELECT markers.name, markers.lat, user_locationtemp.lat AS some_name
FROM markers, user_locationtemp
WHERE markers.lat LIKE CONCAT( user_locationtemp.lat,  '%' )";
```